# How can I add tr and rowspan in a table with jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I'm trying to create a dynamic table, you can see structure here (jsfiddle below):

```
<table id="myTable">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th colspan="2" style="color:white; background-color:aquamarine">Infos client</th>
                        <th colspan="6" style="color:white; background-color:#00ACC1">Commande client</th>
                        <th colspan="3" style="color:white; background-color:#607D8B">Chiffre d'affaires</th>
                        <th></th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Nom</th>
                        <th style="border-right:2px solid rgba(0,0,0,.12)">Prénom</th>
                        <th>Libellé produit</th>
                        <th>Date livraison</th>
                        <th>Date cmde</th>
                        <th>Fournisseur</th>
                        <th>Date théo. liv</th>
                        <th style="border-right:2px solid rgba(0,0,0,.12)"></th>
                        <th>Prix achat TTC</th>
                        <th>Marge TTC</th>
                        <th>Actions</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tfoot>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Nom</th>
                        <th style="border-right:2px solid rgba(0,0,0,.12)">Prénom</th>
                        <th>Libellé produit</th>
                        <th>Date livraison</th>
                        <th>Date cmde</th>
                        <th>Fournisseur</th>
                        <th>Date théo. liv</th>
                        <th style="border-right:2px solid rgba(0,0,0,.12)"></th>
                        <th>Prix achat TTC</th>
                        <th>Marge TTC</th>
                        <th>Actions</th>
                    </tr>
                </tfoot>
                <tbody>
                    <tr id="Newline">
                        <td><input type="text"  /></td>
                        <td style=";border-right:2px solid rgba(0,0,0,.12)"><input type="text"  /></td>
                        <td><input type="text"  /></td>
                        <td><input type="text"  value="" /></td>
                        <td style="border-right:2px solid rgba(0,0,0,.12)"><input type="text"  value=""/></td>
                        <td><input type="text"></td>
                        <td><input  type="text" ></td>
                        <td style="border-right:2px solid rgba(0,0,0,.12)"><a href="#" id="Addproduct">add</a></td>
                        <td><input type="text" /></td>
                        <td><input type="text" /></td>
                        <td><i class="material-icons">save</i></td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
```

Here the link :
https://jsfiddle.net/vg2u9hyc/2/

I want to add a `tr` in the section `Commande client` and add `rowspan` in section `Infos client` and section `Chiffre d'affaires`.

An order can have multiple products so is it possible to add product line (with add button) for the section `Commande client` and add rowspan in other sections?

Comment: Don't use 2 `<thead>`, there should be only one. Each `tr` in one `<thead>` will keep them in 2 separate rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For futur reader, i add classname "IC" to all non-concerning td, and on add click i create new tr line with var row template

```
        var rowNum = $('.LibelleProduit').length;
        rowNum ++;
        var rows = '<tr id="LignePrdt'+rowNum+'"><td> ...</td></tr>';
        $(rows).insertAfter('#Newline');    
        $('.IC').attr('rowspan', rowNum);
```

Comment: Hey there! While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

I think the following code can help your situation, you can customise this code according to your requirements:

```js
var addRow = $(".table1 tr td a");
addRow.click(function() {
  var trContent = $(this).closest('tr');
  $(this).text("Remove");
  $(".table2").append(trContent.wrap('<tr></tr>'));
});
```

```css
td {
  width: 90px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table1">
  <tr>
    <th>Content 1</th>
    <th>Content 2</th>
    <th>Add?</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type='text' /></td>
    <td><input type='password' /></td>
    <td><a class="hide-on-click" href="javascript:void(0)">Add</a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type='text' /></td>
    <td><input type='password' /></td>
    <td><a class="hide-on-click" href="javascript:void(0)">Add</a></td>
  </tr>
</table>

<table class="table2">
  <tr>
    <th>Content 1'</th>
    <th>Content 2'</th>
    <th>Remove?</th>
  </tr>
</table>
```

This is code is basically derived from the situation in your code.

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/thisisdg/gv4smyad/) is a link to the Fiddle. I hope this was helpful.